# How to push changes to other people's remote branch who raised PR in my repository?

Tags: github

My repository: my-repo
Branch name: my-branch
User A: raised PR #123

Now, I checked out `PR-123` using ***`git fetch origin pull/123/head:userA-pr`*** and checked out that new branch (`userA-pr`) to make some changes. Now, how can I push these changes back to PR #123?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I push these changes back to PR #123?

You cannot, since the all idea of a PR is to contribute to a repo you are not the owner of, to which you cannot contribute (push) directly to.

If you need to contribute to another repo (including one from which a PR was done), you need to:

- fork their own repo (which [seems to be possible since 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675994/is-it-possible-to-fork-a-fork-in-github#comment65238299_6896839)), make your branch in it, and make a PR.
- or (in your case) directly make a PR to their fork, as [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286889/how-to-push-changes-to-other-peoples-remote-branch-who-raised-pr-in-my-reposito/43288817#comment73645963_43288817).

Or you simply make a common branch (here `userA-pr`) in your repo and invite the other contributor to make PRs against that branch: see "[Forking a fork of my repo in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18306519/6309)"

Comment: Note that if their repo is a fork of your repo (or a common upstream repo), there's no need to make another fork -- you can create a PR into their repo from any branch in your repo.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.